# The closed ball is contained in the closure of open ball

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

$Bf(a,r) = \{ x \in \mathbb R \mid d(a,x) \le r \}$

I want to show that the the closed ball is contained in the closure of the open ball.

Am guided to take an $x$ from the sphere

Here is what I did,

Let $x$ be an element in $S(a,r)$ then $x$ is in $Bf(a,r)$ because $Bf(a,r) = B(a,r) \cup S(a,r)$.

I then went ahead to show that $x$ is in the closure of the open ball.

Again am guided that I consider a sequence $x_n = x - (1/n)((x-a)/\lVert x-a \rVert)$.

I know that if I take $x_n$ from the open ball $B(a,r)$ the limit of the sequence which is $x$ will be in the closure of the open ball $B(a,r)$.

That would conclude the proof. But then how do I verify that $x_n$ is indeed a sequence of elements in the open ball.

Am working in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: As a first step, perhaps that you could tell us in which space you are working.

Comment: Have you tried calculating the distance from $X_n$ to $a$ and verifying that it is less than $r$?

Comment: Please use mathjax. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation.

Comment: Hint: What you are trying to prove is simply false.